# How to apply form validations for nested components in angular2

Tags: angular

I have plunker demo here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/LX1m2zIpxe3M1Zs5F6zA?p=preview

which has a address component nested in parent component.

How can i apply form validations to the address component and get the values of the address component on form submit? Somebody guide me to get the form values of nested components.

```
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {  
this.myForm = fb.group({  
  'name':  ['', Validators.required],
  'Phone':  ['', Validators.required]  
});
```

}

How do I inject the values of the address component in the parent? What is the best practice for doing it because i am new to doing forms in nested components. Please help.

Comment: Could you use the `required` attribute on the address input field?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this but it will take some work. First you need to create a smart and dumb component relationship, the dumb component holding the html, and the smart component (the parent) holding the logic.

you can read about this pattern [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-smart-components-vs-presentation-components-whats-the-difference-when-to-use-each-and-why/)

you need to use Angular's `@Input` and `@Ouput` to get and send values from the dumb component.

then you can use an Angular `EventEmitter` to send the form values back to the smart component

you can read more [here](https://toddmotto.com/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2)

it is possible to do this with template driven forms. It looks like your current code is a mix of template driven and reactive... I would look into doing this with reactive forms, it will be simpler.

you can find out about reactive forms [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html)